# Can't read file from SDCARD Android Application

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I'm trying to read a json file from the SDCard in the Phone.(SAMSUNG SM-G532M).

But I can't.

I want to put the file in "Downloads" folder, and make the app to look in that folder in particular, for a particular filename.

But i get a FileNotFoundException.

When I debug the application, the path is different from what i spected.
I get "/storage/emulated/0", but I want to read the Download Folder in the SDCARD.

When i use this sentece:

```
ruta_sd = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
```

and I debug the value, it's ponting to :

```
 /storage/emulated/0/Download
```

When I try to navigate with Device File Explorer, i get "Opendir Failed: Permission Denied"

What i'm doing wrong ?

I added this line to manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE">

</uses-permission>
```

notes:
Developing un Android Studio 3.2
Phone : Samsung : SM-G532M ( not emulated )

Thanks in advance!
Best Regards

Comment: Please see this: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting

Comment: Here is a tutorial for runtime permission implementation: https://www.androidhive.info/2016/11/android-working-marshmallow-m-runtime-permissions/

Comment: Here is the complete implementation for runtime permission request: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52508435/9883943

Answer (score 3):

You need to request the runtime.

```
public static final int READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 112;


protected void readSDcardDownloadedFiles() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    } else {
       //Permission is granted
       //Call the method to read file. 
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (grantResults.length > 0
            && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        //Read the files
    } else {
        // permission denied, boo! Disable the
        // functionality that depends on this permission.
    }
}
```

Comment: wait!! great! now it work, I didn't create "overrided" method, where it should go? what id @NonNULL, Android Studio proposed to create an Annotation. And second... where I shoud put the file ? is emulated/0/ a link to sdcard/ ?

Comment: Those are the annonation .. ignore that .. when you override method from studio default gives you that.. You can remove that.. You can keep something like that  public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {